# Django and Reactjs

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack

I'm new to react js and I've seen a lot of write-ups on using react and Django using **django-webpack-loader** and webpack-bundle-tracker and I must say that I've followed them but no success. 
First of all, I'm confused. 
Which server do I run?

```
py manage.py runserver
```

Or

```
webpack --config webpack-config.js -watch
```

What does django-webpack-loader do?

I don't even know if I've asked all the questions I should ask.
All I know is that I've not been successful in linking them

Comment: Just as a general rule you have two basic options: 1. Run two separate servers. Use Django for routing, models, and creating callable API's. Use your react front-end to call the api. It's a modular approach, but you sacrifice having one single code base. 2. Use React as your templating language. I recommend against this since it will take significant tweaking and makes react and Django work in ways in which they were not entirely envisioned to work.

Comment: @Matty It is possible to use React as the templating system and Django for routing with minimal crying, check out: [Reconciling Django and React](https://hackernoon.com/reconciling-djangos-mvc-templates-with-react-components-3aa986cf510a).

Comment: Thanks, @NickSweeting. I think one reason I recommended against this approach was for the lack of precedence or documentation. Your article certainly helps with that. But for a beginner writing non-production code, I think it might be best to learn the SPA (in this case React) and Django separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in the same situation months back, As much I concluded from Your problem, I guess you are struggling to setup Django with React. I would like to share my implementation(it is a standard one everyone recommends to use it.)

Follow These Steps accordingly:-

1. Separate your Frontend with your Backend, What this means is You need to prepare the REST API as your backend Do not use Django templates just make a Restful API which returns some JSON data in every method of your views.py.You can Use `DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK` for making rest-API,it provides lots of functionalities,You will also need to install `CORS-HEADERS` by doing `pip install django-cors-headers` and update your INSTALLED_APPS in  `settings.py` by:-

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
   .......,
   .......
   'corsheaders', 
   ]
   ```

   The whole purpose of cors headers is to allow to make a request which is not running on the same origin. Since your frontend is on a different port from your backend.
2. As soon you finish with your API, Now make your frontend with React to call the API whenever you need.
3. The api server will be running on something like `http://localhost:8000` and frontend server will run `http://localhost:8080`.
4. So You have to visit the port no. `8080` to view the app.and to see the endpoints of the API you need to visit port no. `8000`
5. You can see one of my project [Django React Blog](https://github.com/vinitraj10/Django-React-Blog) that how to maintain react with Django, that can also help you.

Please Raise your doubts if any, though I will suggest to follow this architecture because this will remains the same whether you switch your backend framework or frontend framework, Do let me know if something is wrong in it

Comment: And just to add, I also had to install Django-cors-header to perform Cross domain requests.

Comment: Your welcome,i missed to mention  cors header ,i will update the answer so that it will be helpful for others

Comment: Okay. Please do.

Comment: There are many designs you can use to combine Django + React, a REST API + isolated frontend isn't the only way. This blog post I wrote might help clarify some of the options available: [Reconciling Django with React](https://hackernoon.com/reconciling-djangos-mvc-templates-with-react-components-3aa986cf510a).

Comment: Thanks @nick sweeting for making me aware of that. 